# Что такое "степень распространённости"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, бсп

И как она влияет на постановку знаков препинания в БСП?

Answer (score 3):

Степень распространённости — это количество второстепенных членов в составе простых предложений. Есть короткие предложения, есть длинные. Распространённость предложений оказывает влияние на выбор запятой или  точки с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении.

Для разделения достаточно коротких предложений, обозначающих одновременно или последовательно происходящие события, внутри которых нет своих знаков препинания, используются запятые.

Точка с запятой ставится, если простые предложения значительно распространены (длинные) и имеют внутри себя запятые или другие знаки препинания: *Дубовые кусты разрослись по скатам оврага; около родника зеленеет короткая, бархатная травка.*

Comment: А если выбирать между запятой и двоеточием?

Comment: Здесь степень распространённости ни при чём, только смысловые связи.Двоеточие ставится, если 1) второе предл. указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первом, (тогда можно подставить союзы  потому что, так как) :Ни одной птицы не было слышно: все приютились и замолкли.;2) представляет собой пояснение, (= а именно, то есть): У собак есть рыцарское правило: собаку на привязи или лежачую не трогают.3) дополняет смысл первого (= что) :Глядя на окна, трудно понять: светит еще луна или нет.